# symbolicate line number exactly in swift closure?

Tags: swift, xcode, dwarf, symbolicate, dsym

Is possible to get line number of crash exactly when error is in a swift closure ?

I can't get line number exactly when I re-symbolicate device log or using crash report on firebase, I can just know it happens on which closure, 
 what I miss ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry it is not possible

Your code doesn't exist in the compiled binary because the compiler changes your code code to optimise it in Release.

The solution is to use crash tools (See [Crashlytics](https://fabric.io/home)) or throw out NSLog()

Comment: I want to dump line number from symbolicate